# Book series about a planet partitioned into different habitats; people/aliens were transported into habitats in new bodies

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens

I remember reading (some) of a series of novels in the 1980s (or earlier, I read old books then), where the protagonists were transported to a world that was divided into different habitats suitable for different types of intelligent species. The habitats were not necessarily compatible (some Earth-like, some suitable for chlorine-breathers, etc). People transported to it were transported into a body suitable for the habitat, even if it wasn't the species they were originally.

The main plotline, if I remember correctly, involved the hero trying to find out what was going on, and why this was happening. I don't remember many details.

The author wrote a lot of books where body changing was a major feature. One stand-alone novel featured a pair of heroes conscripted by an alcoholic demon to collect items from alternative worlds, to give the demon the power to destroy an Earth-killer asteroid. They were "injected" into the minds of their counterparts in the alternative worlds, for good and for bad. There were at least two other multibook series with body-transforming protagonists.

Comment: Sounds like something Algis Budrys would write. He liked that theme. See if any of his novels ring a bell: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algis_Budrys#Novels

Comment: I figured this would be a duplicate, but most of the Jack Chalker answers are about his other series.

Comment: You might want also to check James White - "Space hospital" series.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds very much like Jack Chalker's 1977-2000 [Well World series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_World_series):

> The Markovians experimented in species design on the Well World,
> sending the more successful ones into the new universe to populate one
> of these planets. By the time of the stories in the series, the
> Markovians have vanished...
>
> The Well World's surface is composed primarily of 1560 large hexagonal
> regions—called "hexes"—each with an independent and often dramatically
> different climate and ecosystem...

In the first book, [Midnight at the Well of Souls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_at_the_Well_of_Souls):

> At the Well World, Brazil and his companions set off to track down
> Skander and Varnett, to stop them from gaining access to the central
> computer there and do untold mischief to the universe. The
> complication is that travelling through the polar gate on Dalgonia has
> transformed all of the humans, with the exception of Nathan Brazil,
> into members of the various species which inhabit the planet.

Comment: Yes, it does sound very much like Jack Chalker's Well World series. That allowed me to find the other works by Chalker I remembered as well: "And the Devil Will Drag You Under" and the Soul Rider series.

Comment: Series starts out relatively fun, but later entries feature more body horror and enslavement.